# How to loop through scraped items and add them to a dictionary or pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For a project I'm scraping data from futbin players and I would like to add that scraped data to a dict or pandas dataframe. I'm stuck for a couple of hours and would like some help if possible. I will put my code below on what I have so far. This piece of code only prints out the data and from that I'm clueless about what to do.

Code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
urls = ['https://www.futbin.com/21/player/87/pele', 'https://www.futbin.com/21/player/27751/robert-lewandowski']

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    info = soup.find('div', id='info_content')
    rows = info.find_all('td')
    for info in rows:
        print(info.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work you have already done to identify the table you want is good.

- use `read_html()` to convert to a dataframe
- basic transforms to turn it into columns rather than key value pairs
- in `list` comprehension get details of all wanted footballers

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
urls = ['https://www.futbin.com/21/player/87/pele', 'https://www.futbin.com/21/player/27751/robert-lewandowski']

def myhtml(url):
    # use BS4 to get table that has required data
    html = str(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser').find('div', id='info_content').find("table"))
    # read_html() returns a list, take first one,  first column are attribute name, transpose to build DF
    return pd.read_html(html)[0].set_index(0).T

df = pd.concat([myhtml(u) for u in urls])
```

|  | Name | Club | Nation | League | Skills | Weak Foot | Intl. Rep | Foot | Height | Weight | Revision | Def. WR | Att. WR | Added on | Origin | R.Face | B.Type | DOB | Robert Lewandowski FIFA 21 Career Mode | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Edson Arantes Nascimento | FUT 21 ICONS | Brazil | Icons | 5 | 4 | 5 | Right | 173cm | 5'8" | 70 | Icon | Med | High | 2020-09-10 | Prime | nan | Unique | 23-10-1940 | nan |
| 1 | Robert Lewandowski | FC Bayern | Poland | Bundesliga | 4 | 4 | 4 | Right | 184cm | 6'0" | 80 | TOTY | Med | High | 2021-01-22 | TOTY | nan | Unique | nan | Robert Lewandowski FIFA 21 Career Mode |

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with open() and write()

```
 file = open ("filename.txt", "w")
```

The `w` specifies the following :

```
"w" - Write - Opens a file for writing, creates the file if it does not exist
```

And then :

```
 file.write (text_to_save)
```

Be sure to include os.path!

```
import os.path
```